# Android Development, using EditText with DatePicker

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app & I'm stuck now. The app has a EditText, Button and two DatePickers. I want the user to insert a number then select a date on the first DatePicker and when the button is selected I want the inserted number to add with the selected date. Example: if the user insert 4 on the EditText and selects 10 February 2014 on the DatePicker then the new date should be 14 February 2014 "4+10=14" I want the new date to be shown on the second DatePicker & it shouldn't be editable. Please help me

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I don't have the code as yet but I'm sure you could assist me I just need a user to insert a value then add that value to a selected date and show a new date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I coded a sample for you.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        findViewById(R.id.computeDate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText days = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.daysEditText);
                DatePicker datePicker = ((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker));

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(days.getText().toString()));

                DatePicker computedDatePicker = ((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.computedDatePicker));
                computedDatePicker.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/daysEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/computeDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Compute"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/computedDatePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUs = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.US);

private void changeDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = editText.getText().toString(); 
                /*make your counts*/

        Date dataSet = null;
        try {
              dataSet = dateFormatUs.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar.setTime(dataBeginSet);

    }
```